# how to refresh the tabs page in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a page called `Matches` and `feeds`. In the `matches` pages I have 3 tabs as below

```
<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Applied" id="active" #active></ion-tab>
        <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Failed"></ion-tab>
        <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Saved"></ion-tab>
```

So when I navigate from `feed page` to `matches page` I want to navigate to the `tab1Root` tab. When from some other page I navigate or click on the `matches page` Then i want it to navigate to the `tab1Root` automatically and refresh the page. How can I do it? When I navigate from the `feeds page` to `matches page` I'm not getting the output which is present in my `tab1Root` `IonViewDidEnter()`. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

You should use `ionViewWillEnter` instead of `ionViewDidLoad` to reload a tab page every time the user enters this page.

To switch programmatically to another tab:

```
this.navCtrl.parent.select(0) //your tab index
```